# Triggering a True Keyboard Press in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen multiple solutions and have tried them all, but none of them seem to be working for what I am trying to do.

Here is how I'm sending the key-presses right now:

```
$("#choice").autotype(text + "{{enter}}", {delay: 100});
```

It works (as in, it shows the letters in the textbox) but I still need to press enter manually, despite it being part of the line of code above.

I have also attempted using the code I found from another stackoverflow answer:

```
e = jQuery.Event("keypress")
e.which = 13 //choose the one you want
    $("#test").keypress(function(){
     alert('keypress triggered')
    }).trigger(e)
```

(That's the raw version, I changed it a bit to fit my needs but it basically was the same).

I've done a lot of research on this but I can't figure out how to make a true keystroke... is it even possible?

For reference, the keystroke that I'm trying to automate is the enter (return) key.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to press enter, or just add a new line?

Comment: You want to get your enter key pressed automatically! Is that so? Describe what's your final goal.

Comment: @David My final result is just to press enter - not to make a new line. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: @AshadShanto My final goal is to achieve the same result as would be achieved when pressing the standard enter key. In this case, it's to have it be pressed when called by a function. Sorry for not making that clearer.

Comment: True keystrokes are usually very difficult, if not impossible. That's a security feature, and not a flaw. It's usally better, and more reliable to just do what is supposed to happen when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: @David So there's no point in trying other methods to accomplish a true keystroke, correct? As a side question, would the same happen when I try to use commands such as copy & paste?

Comment: You can try, but don't expect to get too far. Even when programming with something like C# or C++, it's still difficult for anything outside of your own piece of software. I think there are ways to access the clipboard, but it usually comes with a prompt asking for the users' permission.